# Is it possible to combine two different custom YOLOv4 models

Tags: object-detection, yolov4

I'm working on an object detection project where I have to identify the type of animals and their posture given an image/video. For this purpose, I have two custom YOLOv4 models which are trained separately. Model 1 identifies the type of animal and Model 2 identifies the posture of the animal. I have converted these models to TensorFlow models.

Now, since both the models use the same image/video as input, I want to combine the outputs of both the models and the final output should display the bounding box of both the models.

I'm stuck at this point, I have been researching the solution for this and I'm confused with various methods. Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you need object detection model as pose identifier - because you've already localized the animal by 1st net.

The easiest (and clearly not very accurate) solution that I see is to use classifier on top of detections (crop bounding box as input) - but in that case the animal anatomy is not taken into account explicitly, but that approach is I guess still good baseline.

For further experiments you can take a look at [these](https://medium.com/axinc-ai/animalpose-pose-esimation-for-animals-700603e0dbae) and [these](https://paperswithcode.com/dataset/animal-pose-dataset) solutions with animal pose estimation, but they are more complex to use